# How redirect input file to stdin to dotnet run command?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

Is possible to redirect input file for stdin of a console application executed with `dotnet run` command line?

Documentation show the `--` option to delimit arguments to `dotnet run` from arguments for application.
But `dotnet run -- < input-file` not work as redirect input.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run#options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that in Windows using PowerShell it works with:

```sh
cat input-file | dotnet run
```

and on Windows using Command it works with:

```sh
dotnet run < input-file
```

The latter works for Linux as well.